# FTP not supported in vcpkg curl port?

Tags: c, curl, libcurl, vcpkg

I need to download a file from an ftp server and I found this example using libcurl [ftpget.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpget.html). It works great in Linux with gcc, but I want my program to work in Windows as well. I noticed there's a port in vcpkg so I installed it with `vcpkg install curl[*]:x64-windows` without any error. However, the problem is that this version of libcurl doesn't seem to support ftp as it just says `* Protocol "ftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl` and fails. If I use http or even https it works just fine. I don't know if ftp is simply not supported or if I need to enable it somewhere. I opened an issue on vcpkg github page but didn't get any reply.

Comment: It certainly sounds like they disabled it by choice. FTP support is always enabled by default in libcurl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vcpkg install curl[non-http]:x64-windows` solved my problem thanks to [myd7349](https://github.com/myd7349).
I guess I did `vcpkg install curl:x64-windows` instead previously and by default `USE_HTTP_ONLY` is set for some reason so other protocols are all disabled.